# Serializing C# Objects having delegate fields using JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, json.net

Although my problem is more of C# / JSON.NET related I will give you the context.

I am building a game in which I need to implement a Challenge System. For those who might be unfamiliar, Challenges are basically clusters of achievements/tasks that you accomplish to earn rewards.

So I need to have Challenges that have list of tasks that are tracked in game.

e.g. Challenge XYZ has 3 task
1. Kill 3 Enemies
2. Collect 2 Stars
3. Reach Score of 100

So first of all I have a **GameState** Class. I am using GameState object to store all the in game data.

```
public class GameState
{
    public static string SaveKey = "GameState";

    public int Blips { get; set; }

    public int ChainClearedCount { get; set;}
    public int DotClearedCount { get; set; }

    public int RetryUsedCount { get; set; }
    public int ContinueUsedCount { get; set; }

    public int LevelAttemptedCount { get; set; }
    public int LevelClearedCount { get; set; }
    public int LevelPlayedCount { get; set; }
    public int LevelFailCount { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<ChainCombos, int> ComboCountBook = new Dictionary<ChainCombos, int>();
    public Dictionary<ChainType, int> ChainTypeCountBook = new Dictionary<ChainType, int>();

    public Dictionary<LevelType, int> LevelTypeCountBook = new Dictionary<LevelType, int>();
    public Dictionary<GameModes, int> LevelModeCountBook = new Dictionary<GameModes, int>();

    public Dictionary<GameModes, int> HighScoreBook = new Dictionary<GameModes, int>();
    public Dictionary<GameModes, int> HighLevelBook = new Dictionary<GameModes, int>();

    public Dictionary<LevelType, int> PlaygroundLevelCountBook = new Dictionary<LevelType, int>();
    public Dictionary<GameDifficulty, int> PlaygroundDifficultyCountBook = new Dictionary<GameDifficulty, int>();

//Followed By Constructors , Accessor Methods and Event Subscribers for GameCore Module
}
```

So the Game State object's respective fields are updated by the GameCore class (not shown) whenever any event occurs.

I am using JSON.NET to serialize this GameState object so that it can be used to load the game data on game launch.

Now I have my Task Class:
The key part of Task Class is Func Value;
This stores a delegate that is used to query the GameState object.

```
public class Task
{
    protected bool Incremental = true;

    Func<int> Value;
    public event Action<float> OnProgress;

    protected int targetValue;
    protected int currentValue;

    public bool Completed = false;

    public float Progress;

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Task(int targetValue, Func<int> Value, bool Incremental, bool ConnectedByDefault) //Constructor
    {
        this.targetValue = targetValue;
        this.Value = Value;
        this.Incremental = Incremental;

        if (ConnectedByDefault)
        {
            ConnectToGame();
        }
    }

    public void ConnectToGame()
    {
        GameController.GameStateEvent += UpdateProgress;
        CalculateProgress();
    }

    public void DisconnectFromGame()
    {
        GameController.GameStateEvent -= UpdateProgress;
    }

    protected virtual void OnComplete() { Completed = true; }

    protected void UpdateProgress(GameState s)
    {
        if (Value() > currentValue)
        {
            CalculateProgress();

            if (OnProgress != null)
            {
                OnProgress(Progress);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void CalculateProgress()
    {
        currentValue = Value();

        if (currentValue < targetValue)
        {
            if (Incremental)
            {
                Progress = ((float)currentValue / (float)targetValue);
            }
            else
            {
                Progress = 0f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Progress = 100f;
            OnComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

Now if i have to declare a Task i do something like this

```
Task a = new Task(200, () => GameController.CurrentGameState.DotClearedCount, true, false);
```

As you can see what I am doing is sending a delegate that will be allocated to Value field of the task and will be used internally to query the Game-state object's indicated field (in this case DotClearedCount).

My issue is that I have to serialize the task objects since I need to keep track of player's task progress over multiple game sessions.

JSON.NET is incapable of serializing delegate fields of objects as far as I know. I mean I checked storing a delegate and the JSON output was something like "delegatEntry = null".

So I am unable to wrap my head around the issue of how I am going to save my Task objects such that when they are deserialized and constructed by JSON.NET they get linked back to my GameState object.

I looked in LINQ queries I am still unable to find anything concrete that will help me. I mean as far as I understood I can build LINQ queries on objects like Lists and Dictionaries but then again my GameState objects have a lot of Dictionaries that I want to target separately for different tasks.

Comment: If I were you I would transform the dictionaries into classes and then store them in lists in the game state class and thus a workaround for the generic deserialization from JSON.

Comment: I would create a class, for example "ComboCountBookClass" with two properties public ChainCombo {get; set;} public Count {get; set;} and in the GameState class instead of a dictionary I would use a List<ComboCountBookClass> { get; set; }. If you need an even more complete example I'll post it as an answer.